# Why postgres saves date in different ways?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, date

I have Spring Boot app with PostgreSQL. When I save a date like 2020-07-28 в 17:30:00, in PostgreSQL it looks 2020-07-28 в 06:30:00. Sometimes the difference is 12 hours sometimes 11. In front-end it comes in right way, but when I export it in cvs wrong date comes out. Why it happens and how it fix?
These are my variables:

```
    @NotNull
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/mm/yyyy")
    private Date startDate;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/mm/yyyy")
    private Date endDate;
```

Comment: Why are you using java.util.Date in the first place?

Comment: `2020-07-28 в 17:30:00` is not a `date` value, but a `timestamp`. That should be `java.time.LocalDateTime` in your Java code (or even better: `java.time.OffsetDateTime`)

Comment: What is your JVM default time zone? What is the type of your column? The problem is likely that PostgreSQL normalizes to UTC or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

The java.util.Date is pretty annoying to be honest. If you want to play with it, in database or in front you should better use LocalDateTime as said. However if you want to continue using java.util.Date, I have found a way that worked for me but is pretty much just bypassing the problem. If you want you can try using it like that :

```
 Date startDate;
 SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
 System.Out.println(formater.format(startDate));
```

I used this to insert in DB and in front-end and worked pretty well for me

Comment: FYI, the terribly flawed date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), `GregorianCalendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) classes built into Java 8 and later.

Answer (score 0):

## Avoid `Date`

Never use the `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date` classes. Along with `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`, these are now legacy, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes.

## *java.time* classes with JDBC 4.2+

If you are trying to record a moment, a specific point on the timeline, use:

- In Postgres, a column of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. Notice the `WITH` rather than `WITHOUT` (which cannot represent a moment).
- In Java, `Instant`, [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html), or [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

JDBC 4.2 and later lets us exchange *java.time* objects with the database. But oddly, JDBC 4.2 requires support only for `OffsetDateTime` but not the two more commonly used types. Fortunately, converting is easy.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of(  2020 , Month.JULY , 28 ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 17 , 30 ) ;
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z ) ;
```

You *may* be able to pass that to your particular JDBC driver.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , zdt ) ;
```

If not, convert to `OffsetDateTime`.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , zdt.toOffsetDateTime() ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

Adjust to your desired time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant​( z ) ;
```

Present to the user, as text, localized.

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

See the same moment in UTC. A `Instant` object is always in UTC, by definition.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

Using the code seen here will eliminate your time zone surprises.

All this has been covered many many many times already on Stack Overflow. So I was brief. Search to learn more.

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy and modern) and in standard SQL]